# Idea for rapid healing?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, medicine

I'll keep this a short as I can. For a biological worldbuilding exercise where humans possess far greater biological abilities. I imagined a pancreas-sized organ that contained a huge reserve cache of dehydrated stem cells, and whenever there is any injury the body demands massive amounts of water to hydrate and mobilize these stem cells to go and fix the problem.

I did some *light* research into this problem and it told me that there really isn't any HUGE problem that ends up stopping things like limb regeneration, and traits like these haven't evolved purely because the chances of surviving a wound that requires a huge reserve cache of stem cells is so small that its just not worth it.

So I was just looking to get some feedback and consultations on the biological problems and challenges that it would face where it to be real?

Comment: This isn't a discussion site. Asking for feedback and consultations isn't a good use of this site's format. Can you try to [edit] this to ask a single, specific, non-opinion-based question?

Comment: If you look at WB:SE [guidelines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you need to be facing a specific problem than looking more casually for some feedbacks ^^. If you want to get some feedbacks on a system and whether it's plausible or not as stated, you can try to ask a [tag:reality-check] question. But in order to do that we need far more information about your system, and the specific point you're not sure it's believable or not.

Answer (score 1):

> dehydrated stem cells, and whenever there is any injury the body demands massive amounts of water to hydrate and mobilize these stem cells

This is not plausible.  Dehydrating eukaryotic cells will cause so much disruption to their internal structure that you would not be able to add water an return them to "life".

> there really isn't any HUGE problem that ends up stopping things like limb regeneration, and traits like these haven't evolved purely because the chances of surviving a  wound that requires [modern medicine] is so small that its just not worth it

There is a certain amount of speculation here, as we do not know what a human that could regenerate its limbs would look like, but I think this could be better phrased as a mammal like a human would take so long to regenerate from a serious that it would die before it happened.  Our current healing process is much quicker than the growth process, so we can stop bleeding (blood clotting) and seal wounds (scar tissue) quicker than we could remodel our tissue to recover all functionality.

Our cells are capable of [reverting to pluripotent stem cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_pluripotent_stem_cell), and skin fibroblasts are the cells that are usually used.  I do not see that you need to introduce a store of stem cells doing nothing.

I think you could plausibly do what you want with simply the addition of a method of keeping humans alive when injured for longer (could be improved social structure during the evolutionary period), combined with physiological mechanism to direct existing functionality towards reconstituting damaged tissue rather than patching it as quickly as possible.